# Sonicwall TZ210 Issues

Tags: https, sonicwall, rds

Have a client who has a TZ 210. We had them setup with forwards for RDP to their desktops at the office and then RDS to the server for a remote office who will be moving in a few months and didn't want to setup a site-to-site until they move to their finished offices. They came to us a couple of weeks back asking us to get it setup so one of their App servers would be reachable on a different WAN IP address on port 443.
I setup a external address object with the 3rd of their 5 public IPs in their block. I setup an address object for the internal IP of the app server. I then setup firewall access rule for From WAN to LAN Service 443 Source Public IP Des Private IP users all and schedule always on. Then I setup the NAT and reflective NAT for Original Source - Any Trans Source - Original, Original Destination - Public Trans Destination - Private Service - HTTPS Trans Serivce - Original Inbound Interface X1 (WAN) Outbound Any

This allows the applications web page to work as intended but all users on RDS connections start getting kicked off around once a minute. When I disable the NAT and Firewall rule the RDS users can stay connected, but of course the application's web page doesn't work. I am not sure what is causing the issue for the RDS users and any ideas to try to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, increase TCP timeout on those specific Firewall rules.  Not uncommon.

https://www.cybersecure.com.au/support/?p=1197

Comment: Ok changed the TCP timeout, restarted the firewall and then turned the rules and policies back on for the 2nd Public IP. Connected to a RDS session and was kicked off about 55 seconds later with a reconnect about 2 seconds after the disconnect, so issue still persisted. Since the original post yesterday morning I have narrowed down the disconnection cause to most likely being the reflective policy that the wizard created. When it is disabled but everything else enabled the disconnects didn't happen, but at the same time the web application no longer functioned either.